# trimming string, removing last character in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am having troubles removing backslash from my string. 
The string is like this "3adsadas34\".
I want to remove the backslash at the end, I tried with:

```
urlContent = realUrl.Remove(realUrl.Length - 1, 1);
```

But it doesn't want to work. 
I would like to know if I can use regex, and if I can, maybe someone can provide regex sample for removing '\' from that string, or some other way to remove the backslash is more then welcome.
Thanks in advance, Laziale

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
urlContent = realUrl.TrimEnd('\\');
```

Note: You have to escape the backslash.

```
char ch = '\\';
string s = "\\";
string verbatimString = @"\";
```

---

Your `Remove` code looks OK. `realUrl.Substring(0, realUrl.Length-1)` would do the same. The problem might be somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

you can use trim end,

```
realUrl.TrimEnd('\\');
```

Remember, this will remove all trailing occurences of '\'

Comment: I didn't vote you down, but I think we know what you were going for, but missed escaping the character itself

Answer (score 1):

For example a very naive implementation:

```
public static string RemoveTrailingBackslash(string text)
{
 if (text.EndsWith("\\") && text.Length > 1)
  return text.Substring(0, text.Length - 1);

 return text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
urlContent = realUrl.TrimEnd('\\');
```

Keep in mind that you must escape the backslash with another backslash in order for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Do this way:-

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"\\$", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove *all* backslashes at the end, call [`string.TrimEnd('\\')`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx) as the other posters wrote.

To remove only the last (assuming that there possible are multiple backslashes at the end), do something like:

```
if ( realUrl!=null && realUrl.EndsWith('\\') )
{
    urlContent = realUrl.Substring(0, realUrl.Length-1 );
}
else
{
    urlContent = realUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
urlContent = realUrl.Substring(0, realUrl.Length - 1);
```

should also work

Answer (score 0):

```
 string realUrl="3adsadas34\\";
 string urlContent = realUrl.Remove(realUrl.Length - 1, 1);
```